# jquery clickable map with points and google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, clickable

I have a problem.
Trying to create a map jpg or svg clickable points, so that clicking on a point on the map showed the information to the left of the page with information about the point of a div id and bottom showed the location in google map. Schematic present in the picture.

[image: Thanks in advance for your help!]

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

1. You can integrate maps in your page either from google or Leaflet. Leaflet provides a easy way to integrate maps using javascript.
2. After using javascript you can add markers to map and can add whatever information as you want either in popupor somewhere else.
3. [Follow the Leaflet link](http://leafletjs.com/)